# How to emulate Emacs’ transpose-words in Vim?

Tags: vim, emacs, editor, usability

Emacs has a useful `transpose-words` command which lets one exchange the word before the cursor with the word after the cursor, preserving punctuation.

For example, ‘`stack |overflow`’ + M-t = ‘`overflow stack|`’ (‘`|`’ is the cursor position).

`<a>|<p>` becomes `<p><a|>`.

Is it possible to emulate it in Vim? I know I can use `dwwP`, but it doesn’t work well with punctuation.

*Update:* No, `dwwP` is *really* not a solution. Imagine:

```
SOME_BOOST_PP_BLACK_MAGIC( (a)(b)(c) )
//             with cursor here ^
```

Emacs’ M-t would have exchanged `b` and `c`, resulting in `(a)(c)(b)`.

What works is `/\w 
yiwNviwpnviwgp`. But it spoils `""` and `"/`. Is there a cleaner solution?

*Update²:*

## Solved

```
:nmap gn :s,\v(\w+)(\W*%#\W*)(\w+),\3\2\1\r,<CR>kgJ:nohl<CR>
```

Imperfect, but works.

Thanks Camflan for bringing the `%#` item to my attention. Of course, it’s all on the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip47), but I didn’t realize it could solve the problem of *exact* (Emacs got it completely right) duplication of the `transpose-words` feature.

Comment: I'm having a hard time googling "%#". What do they signify here?

Comment: Use the built-in Vim help: :h /\%#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are from my .vimrc and work well for me.

```
" swap two words
:vnoremap <C-X> <Esc>`.``gvP``P
" Swap word with next word
nmap <silent> gw    "_yiw:s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<cr><c-o><c-l> *N*
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like the visual map. Something to be careful of however is that because the column number of a mark doesn't change, if the two words you are swapping are on the same line then you *must* start with deleting the first word from the left and then <C-X> the second word from the left, not the other way around (the exception to the exception being when the two words are actually the same length).

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the situation, you can use the W or B commands, as in dWwP.  The "capital" versions skip to the next/previous space, including punctuation.  The f and t commands can help, as well, for specifying the end of the deleted range.

There's also a discussion on the [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip47) about various swapping techniques.

Answer (score 5):

In the middle of a line, go to the first letter of the first word, then do

```
dw wP
```

At the end of a line (ie the last two words of the line), go to the space between the words and do

```
2dw bhP
```

*From the handy [Equivalence of VIM & Emacs commands](http://danzig.jct.ac.il/unix_class/emacs-vi-Commands.html)*

---

You could add shortcut keys for those by adding something like the following to your vimrc file:

```
map L dwwP
map M 2dwbhP
```

In that case, SHIFT-L (in command-mode) would switch words in the middle of the line and SHIFT-M would do it at the end.

*NB:  This works best with space-separated words and doesn't handle the OP's specific case very well.*

Answer (score 2):

There's a tip on http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip10. But I choose to roll my own.
My snippet has two obvious advantages over the method mentioned in the tip: 1) it works when the cursor isn't in a word. 2) it won't high-light the entire screen.

It works almost like emacs 'transpose-words', except that when transposition is impossible, it does nothing. (emacs 'transpose-words' would blink and change cursor position to the beginning of current word.)

```
"transpose words (like emacs `transpose-words')
function! TransposeWords()
    if search('\w\+\%#\w*\W\+\w\+')
    elseif search('\w\+\W\+\%#\W*\w\+')
    endif
    let l:pos = getpos('.')
    exec 'silent! :s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/'
    call setpos('.', l:pos)
    let l:_ = search('\(\%#\w\+\W\+\)\@<=\w\+')
    normal el
endfunction

nmap <silent> <M-right> :call TransposeWords()<CR>
imap <silent> <M-right> <C-O>:call TransposeWords()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dwwP or dWwP as Mark and CapnNefarious have said, but I have a few notes of my own:

- If the cursor is on the first letter of the second word, as in the example you gave, you can use dwbP (or dWbP to handle punctuation);
- If the cursor is in the middle of the word, you can use dawbP/daWbP.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [transpose-words script](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3656) on vim.org that works beautifully.